# Assembly - Draw A Circle

Tags: assembly, geometry, tasm, dosbox

I am now trying to draw a circle in Assembly but for some reason it doesn't work, DOSBox freezes and I can't seem to understand why. Moreover, the circle doesn't appear on the screen. I found most of the code online and I am trying to use it and understand what it does but I can't seem to find any mistakes here.

Here is the code:

```
player1disccolor db 0Eh
Player1Disc:
    push 0a000h 
    pop es                   
    mov dx, 20               
    mov di, 20               
    mov al, [player1disccolor]               
    mov bx, 30                
    call Player1Disc       
    mov ah, 0 
    int 10h                     
    mov bp,0                 
    mov si,bx                

Disc1:                
    call Set8pixels                             
    sub  bx,bp               
    inc  bp                   
    sub  bx,bp                
    jg   Disc2                  
    add  bx,si                
    dec  si                   
    add  bx,si               

Disc2:                
    cmp si,bp              
    jae Disc1                  
    ret 

Set8pixels:           
    call Set4pixels             

Set4pixels:           
    xchg bp,si               
    call Set2pixels             

Set2pixels:
    neg si 
    push di 
    add di,si 
    add di,dx 
    mov [es:[di+bp]],al 
    sub di,bp 
    stosb 
    pop di 
    ret
```

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page where you found this code on?

Comment: If you want to learn assembler, the chose a modern CPU such as arm. It is much nicer, and easier to program. There are emulators and most mobile phones & the raspberry-pi have this CPU. (and I think they out sell x86 by about 5 to 1)

Comment: David, I do not know how to use the debugger in Notepad++. Margaret, http://computer-programming-forum.com/45-asm/67a67818aff8a94a.htm Richard, unfortunately I have to use this assembler because this is what we are being taught at school.

Comment: @richard: I don't think 32bit/64bit x86 user-space code is particularly hard to learn, compared to ARM.  It's only a mess when people are forced to learn 16bit (segmentation, limited addressing modes), and the weird DOS or BIOS system-call API at the same time.  What makes learning asm cool, and different from other languages, is executing it natively on your desktop, and debugging it directly with the same debugger you use for C programs, not in an emulator/interpreter.  And also calling your asm functions from C compiled natively.

Comment: I think teaching asm along with a whole new system-call API and an emulated environment is way too much at once, and many SO questions reflect the fact that people haven't separated the DOS system-call API/ABI (or the MIPS simulator system calls, or whatever) from the rest of coding in assembly.

Comment: I remember a few years back I had to write a context switch routine (dispatcher), it tool about an hour for ARM, and over a day and 2 people for x86. I remember that at lunchtime or the first day, we had still not got the full list of x86 registers. (and ARM has many more registers than x86, and I can remember them all by name)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Player1Disc:
>     push 0a000h 
>     pop es                   
>     mov dx, 20               
>     mov di, 20               
>     mov al, [player1disccolor]               
>     mov bx, 30                
>     call Player1Disc
> ```

With this last instruction `call Player1Disc` the code is recursively **and endlessly** calling itself without doing anything useful! This inevitably will crash the program.

---

Even if the above error wasn't there the next 2 lines would set the video mode to a undefined mode because the AL register wasn't properly set!

```
mov ah, 0 <= This is the BIOS SetVideoMode function
int 10h
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Fifoernik. I don't understand why the AL register wasn't set properly and how can I make the Player1Disc function stop? The only way I know is to compare it with something and I don't think I can use it in this case.

Comment: @KatomPower: sounds to me like you have no idea what the instructions does. Try to get back to some introduction... like for example `int 10h` is calling BIOS services, the "ah" says BIOS what kind of service you are asking for, rest of registers has to be set per service as needed. From the es=0xA000 I would say you are interested into 320x200 256 color mode? The `mov ax,13h int 10h` will do it (ah = 0 [select gfx mode], al = 19 [320x200 256color BIOS gfx mode]  ... the `ax` is comprised from both `al` and `ah` registers, so by single `mov` you set both of them, `al` is the lower 8 bit part)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you've done with the program that you found on [the other forum](http://computer-programming-forum.com/45-asm/67a67818aff8a94a.htm).
This is what I copied from there. It's as straightforward as can be.

```
.MODEL    TINY 
.286 
.CODE 
  ORG       100h 
Start:
  mov       ax,13h 
  int       10h                 ;mode 13h 
  push      0a000h 
  pop       es                  ;es in video segment 
  mov       dx,160              ;Xc 
  mov       di,100              ;Yc 
  mov       al,04h              ;Colour 
  mov       bx,50               ;Radius 
  call      Circle              ;Draw circle 
  mov       ah,0 
  int       16h                 ;Wait for key 
  mov       ax,3 
  int       10h                 ;Mode 3 
  mov       ah,4ch 
  int       21h                 ;Terminate 

;*** Circle 
; dx= x coordinate center 
; di= y coordinate center 
; bx= radius 
; al= colour 
Circle:
  mov       bp,0                ;X coordinate 
  mov       si,bx               ;Y coordinate 
c00:
  call      _8pixels            ;Set 8 pixels 
  sub       bx,bp               ;D=D-X 
  inc       bp                  ;X+1 
  sub       bx,bp               ;D=D-(2x+1) 
  jg        c01                 ;>> no step for Y 
  add       bx,si               ;D=D+Y 
  dec       si                  ;Y-1 
  add       bx,si               ;D=D+(2Y-1) 
c01: 
  cmp       si,bp               ;Check X>Y 
  jae       c00                 ;>> Need more pixels 
  ret 
_8pixels:
  call      _4pixels            ;4 pixels 
_4pixels:
  xchg      bp,si               ;Swap x and y 
  call      _2pixels            ;2 pixels 
_2pixels:
  neg       si 
  push      di 
  add       di,si 
  imul      di,320 
  add       di,dx 
  mov       es:[di+bp],al 
  sub       di,bp 
  stosb 
  pop       di 
  ret 
END Start
```

To correct your own version keep the complete *Circle* procedure and call it with `call Circle`. I further suggest you setup the `ES` segment register within the *Circle* procedure, it's a more robust way of doing things.

```
Player1Disc:
  mov  dx, 20                 ;CenterX
  mov  di, 20                 ;CenterY
  mov  al, [player1disccolor] ;Color              
  mov  bx, 30                 ;Radius
  call Circle
  ...
  ALL THE OTHER CODE YOU NEED
  ...
Circle:
  push 0A000h 
  pop  es                   
  mov  bp, 0                 
  mov  si, bx
  ...
```

---

The reasons why your original code crashed were already given by [Fifoernik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3628942/fifoernik)